# convert string to 2d-array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

For example I get an string (example = ".|x") whenever an x pops up i must push true to my array, whenever an '.' pops up i must push false to my array. and where my problem lays is that whenever an "|" pops up i must start a new row of booleans making it an 2d array

```
function parse(str) {
    let result = [];
    let array = [];
    for (let char of str){
        if (char === "x") {
            result.push(true);
        } if (char === "."){
            result.push(false);
        } if (char === "|"){
            result.push(array);

        }
    }
    return [result];
}

this code just returns [[false, [], true]]
```

this is what i should be getting

[[false], [true]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Split the string at every pipe: `|`

   **string.split('|')**
2. Iterate through the resulting array wherein the callback of `.map()` method takes each string and converts it into an array of characters.

   `string.split('|')`**.map(str => [...[...str]** `step 3` **])**

   The outer brackets and spread operator: **[...**`[...str] step 3` **]** will convert the returned value from `step 3` into an array. The inner brackets and spread operator: `[...`**[...str]** `step 3 ]` will split the string into characters.
3. Each array of characters from `step 2` is then iterated through using [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) method which is a combination of `.map()` and `.flat()` methods. In the callback, the return should be returned as a separate sub-array -- furthermore should you need a return omitted, simply pass an empty array. In this callback, it will compare each character to a `'x'` and return `[true]` or `[false]` (**note:** returned arrays are flattened).

   `string.split('|').map(str => [...[...str]`**.flatMap(chr => chr === 'x' ? [true] : [false])** `])`

```js
// Raw data for a 6x8 table
const data = `........|....xxxx|xxxxxxxx|x.x.x.x.|x..xx..x|.xx..xx.`;

const bool2D = string => string.split('|').map(str => [...[...str].flatMap(chr => chr === 'x' ? [true] : [false])]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(bool2D(data)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function parse(str) {
    let result = [];
    let array = [];
    for (let char of str){
        if (char === "x") {
            array.push(true);
        } if (char === "."){
            array.push(false);
        } if (char === "|"){
            result.push(array);
            array = []
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

That will create a new row so you can add more bool values, if that is what I understood from your problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
function parse(str) {
    let result = [];
    for (let char of str){
        if (char === "x") {
            result.push(true);
        } if (char === "."){
            result.push(false);
        } if (char === "|"){
            result = result.map( e => [e]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(parse('.|x')); // logs [ [ false ], true ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterative solution.

```
function parse(str) {
  const result = [];
  let array = [];
  for (const char of str) {
    switch (char) {
      case 'x':
      case '.':
        array.push(char === 'x');
        break;
      case '|':
        result.push(array);
        array = [];
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Functional solution.

```
const parse = (str) => str.split('').reduce((acc, char) => {
  switch (char) {
    case 'x':
    case '.':
      acc[acc.length-1].push(char === 'x');
      break;
    case '|':
      acc.push([]);
  }
  return acc;
}, []).slice(0, -1);
```

Both solutions run in O(n) time. I wrote these under the assumption that the function should do nothing if a string contains another character (it could throw an `Error`?) and that it should only push any subarray to the 2D list if there is at least a `'|'` present. If a string does not contain a `'|'` then it will return an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

This code does the trick

```
function parse(str) {
    let result = [];
    let array = [];
    for (let char of str){
        if (char === "x") {
            array.push(true);
        } if (char === "."){
            array.push(false);
        } if (char === "|"){
            result.push(array);
            array = []
        }


    }
    result.push(array);
    return result;
}
```